# How to add attributes for <script> tag in HAML using CoffeeScript?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, haml

I'm using HAML with Coffeescript and have an issue with custom tag `<script>` being added.

I have `index.haml` with some content:

```
%h1 Some text

:coffee
 $ ->
   $('.some_html_elm').some_function;
...
```

This markup is generating HTML with a `<script>` tag.

I need to add an attribute `data-turbolinks-eval=false` (code-examples.net/en/q/13ba02e) to the `<script>` tag, but I can`t find a solution.

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

My bad :(

You should use `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->` for this case without any additional attributes

Comment: If this is intended to be the answer to the question please flesh it out with a better explanation.